# what is the exact method of aligning text to centre?

Tags: html, css

I have started building my first page but then when I have mentioned justify content and align content at center then also my heading are not coming at center.This is my `css` and `html` codes below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600');

body{
    font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    
}
.heading{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align: center;
    align-content:center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
    
}
.heading-2{
    display:flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
    
}
.heading h1{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 120px;
    color: #fff;
}
.heading-2 h1{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 120px;
    color: #fff;
}
.heading{
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529387814771-bd36b10c01ca?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80);
    background-size: cover;
}
.heading-2{
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529387814771-bd36b10c01ca?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   
    
    <title>Stan-Lee</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
     <body>
         <section class="heading" text-align="centre"><h1> Tribute</h1></section>
         <section class="heading-2"><h1>The End</h1></section>
    
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us relevant code snippets of what you have tried so far.

Comment: And try replacing the above flex properties with `text-align: center` and see if that works.

Comment: There are a ton of them, but we can only recommend the best one for what you're doing if you give us code to work with :D

Comment: To get help, you need to help by providing sample code. Otherwise it's a guessing game and a waste of time for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

While align-content and align-items are very similar, `align-items` is the one you're going to want to use for centering the content perpendicularly.

[Here's a great blog post explaining the difference.](https://medium.com/@wendersyang/what-the-flex-is-the-difference-between-justify-content-align-items-and-align-content-5fd3694f5259)

I have updated your snippet below and as you can see, the titles align correctly in the center.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600');

body{
    font-family:'Montserrat',sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    
}
.heading{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items:center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
    
}
.heading-2{
    display:flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
}
.heading h1{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 120px;
    color: #fff;
}
.heading-2 h1{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 120px;
    color: #fff;
}
.heading{
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529387814771-bd36b10c01ca?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80);
    background-size: cover;
}
.heading-2{
    background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1529387814771-bd36b10c01ca?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   
    
    <title>Stan-Lee</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
     <body>
         <section class="heading" text-align="centre"><h1> Tribute</h1></section>
         <section class="heading-2"><h1>The End</h1></section>
    
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much..it works perfectly..there are so many `css` tags to learn and understand.